# C# WPF DataGrid bind IEnumerable<someclass>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to do some DataGrid in WPF MVVM. I'm new to this.

Why my simple solution is not working?

I want to Bind this:

```
public IEnumerable<ZenonClasses.RGMRecipeValue> Values
        {
            get => SelectedPhase?.ValueItems;
        }
```

to this:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Values.VarName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

But my DataGrid is empty.
I guess I need some configuration and I'm looking for simple solution, unfortunately didn't find anything that would enough good explained for me.

Comment: You need to set the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to True. Try this `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns = "True" />`

Comment: It's usual to bind an observablecollection rather than ienumerable. You need that Values property to be in the datacontext of your datagrid ( which will inherit from the window it's in ) and bind itemssource to that. You do not need to set autogeneratecolumns to true - that's the default.

Comment: Are you setting the [`DataContext`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/11/understanding-the-datacontext/)? You should bind the `ItemSource` on the Values property, not the `Values.VarName`

Comment: To quote the docs: "Binding IEnumerable to an ItemsControl forces WPF to create a wrapper IList<T> object, which means your performance is impacted by the unnecessary overhead of a second object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will assume your window (xaml) has a datacontext which is the Model View class that implements the property you're mentioning (Values).
If not, then you have to make sure this happens. What I usally do is assign it on the window code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new YOURVIEWMODELCLASS();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
```

Then, your DataGrid control needs to have a definition of colums, I don't see this in your code sample, but you need to provide them, so the control knows how many columns to "paint", this is explained here in detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2

Then the "Values" property itself. Your current type is IEnumerable, you may need to change this type to ObservableCollection as this suits better the Databinding in WPF.

Finally, make sure your ModelView class implements the INotifyPopertyChanged interface as it's the mechanism WPF provides to make databinding work effectively. Here's a sample code from one of my apps:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private ObservableCollection<Results> searchResults;

 public ObservableCollection<Results> SearchResults { get => searchResults; set { searchResults = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }


#region INotifyPropertyChanged

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

#endregion

//Other code here.... 

}
```

In this particular case, my propery SearchResults is displayed in the window using a DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Term" Binding="{Binding SearchedTopic}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Match Count" Binding="{Binding FoundPaths.Count}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding FoundPaths}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Found" Binding="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you bind the grid to an ObservableCollection then you do not need to use INotifyPropertyChanged on that ObservableCollection too as its already implemented.